# Qt equivalent of GtkInfoBar

Tags: qt, qt4, gtk

I just stumbled on GtkInfoBar ([Documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkInfoBar.html) / [Example with screen shot](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/3.2/sec-infobar.html.en)).

I have my own half assed implementations of this functionality in some Qt apps. I've struggled to get the themeing to work correctly.

Is there an equivalent of GtkInfoBar for Qt?

Comment: What are you trying to do, theme-wise? QStatusBar and all other Qt widgets have basically the same [styles api](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/stylesheet-reference.html), but what is the goal?

Comment: 1. The themeing is hard to get right, i.e. to fit the os theme. Mine allways seem to break on dark os themes.

2. The message box like api of GtkInfoBar makes it easier to port/switch between existing message box code.

I guess there is no such thing. I guess I should log a qt bug.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a [`QDockWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdockwidget.html).
In your use case you have to:

- Hide the title bar
- Hide title button box (like close)
- Forbid moving and floating option

Then you can add all the widgets you need in it. For theming it you can use style sheet like for all other widgets.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I think that the closest to what you are looking for is the [QStatusBar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstatusbar.html).

I am not sure about themes but you can add an remove widgets to the bar as needed.